# How to Cast Enum To Int

Tags: c#, enums, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to cast an Enum to int value, there is an extension that cast the Enum to seletListItem in my service which look like this

```
 public Dictionary<int, string> GetWorkingDays()
    {
        var days = typeof(WorkDays).ToSelectList();
        return days;
    }
```

then I return it to my view using view bag like this

```
 ViewBag.WorkingDays = _vendorService.GetWorkingDays().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.Key.ToString(), Text = x.Value });
```

now When one of the Enum is choose from the view it returns int value to my controller how can i cast that int to my service initialisations...

thank you for your time please

this my service

```
public int AddVendor(string companyname, string addressOne, string addressTwo, string city, string state, string country, string phone, string email, int workingDays)
    {
        var vendor = new Vendor()
        {
            CompanyName = companyname,
            AddressLineOne = addressOne,
            AddressLineTwo = addressTwo,
            City = city,
            State = state,
            Country = country,
            Phone = phone,
            Email = email,
            IsActive = true,
            RegistrationDate = DateTime.Now
            WorkingDays = //casting here to collect the parameter (int workingDays)
        };
        _unitOfWork.VendorRepository.Insert(vendor);
        _unitOfWork.VendorRepository.Save();

        return vendor.Id;
    }
```

here is the enum

```
public enum WorkDays
{
    EveryDay, MondayToFriday, MondayToSaturday, FridayToSunday, SaturdayAndSunday
}
```

this is the controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(VendorViewModel model)
    {
        //
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.WorkingDays = _vendorService.GetWorkingDays().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.Key.ToString(), Text = x.Value });
            ViewBag.Error = false;
            return View(model);
        }

        var vendor = _vendorService.AddVendor(model.CompanyName, model.AddressLineOne, model.AddressLineTwo, model.City, model.State, model.Country,model.OpeningTime,model.ClosingTime, model.Phone, model.Email, model.WorkingDays);
        if (vendor != 0)
        {
            _vendorService.AddVendorContact(model.FirstName, model.LastName, model.MobileNumber1, model.MobileNumber2, model.EmailAddress, vendor);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");


    }
```

My Model

```
public class Vendor : BaseDataObject
{
   public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string AddressLineOne { get; set; }
    public string AddressLineTwo { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string OpeningTime { get; set; }
    public string ClosingTime { get; set; }
    public WorkDays WorkingDays { get; set; }

}

public enum WorkDays
{
    EveryDay, MondayToFriday, MondayToSaturday, FridayToSunday, SaturdayAndSunday
}
```

then this is the view Model

```
public class VendorViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Company Name")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Address Line One")]
    public string AddressLineOne { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Address Line Two")]
    public string AddressLineTwo { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [Phone]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid E-Mail Address")]
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Opening Time")]
    public string OpeningTime { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Closing Time")]
    public string ClosingTime { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Working Days")]
    public int WorkingDays { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: did you have any google from this?

Comment: By default, `enum` is `int` so you can do straightforward: `int result = (int) workDays;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you want. I think you actually want to convert an int to an enum rather than the other way around. to cast an int to an enum is the same as casting any data type. **(YourEnum)intVar**.

```
public int AddVendor(string companyname, string addressOne, string addressTwo, string city, string state, string country, string phone, string email, int workingDays)
    {
        var vendor = new Vendor()
        {
            // skipped for brevity
            WorkingDays = (WorkDays)workingDays
        };
        _unitOfWork.VendorRepository.Insert(vendor);
        _unitOfWork.VendorRepository.Save();

        return vendor.Id;
    }

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(VendorViewModel model)
    {
        //... skipped for brevity
        var vendor = _vendorService.AddVendor(model.CompanyName, model.AddressLineOne, model.AddressLineTwo, model.City, model.State, model.Country,model.OpeningTime,model.ClosingTime, model.Phone, model.Email, (int)model.WorkingDays);
        //... skipped for brevity

    }
```

That said if you change the workingDays parameter from int workingDays parameter to an enum parameter, you won't need to cast. E.g.

```
 public int AddVendor(string companyname, string addressOne, string addressTwo, string city, string state, string country, string phone, string email, int workingDays)
```

change to

```
public int AddVendor(string companyname, string addressOne, string addressTwo, string city, string state, string country, string phone, string email, WorkDays workingDays)
{
    var vendor = new Vendor()
    {
        // skipped for brevity
        WorkingDays = workingDays
    };
    _unitOfWork.VendorRepository.Insert(vendor);
    _unitOfWork.VendorRepository.Save();

    return vendor.Id;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can cast it as below !!

```
int x = (int)WorkDays.MondayToFriday;
```

And if you want extension method for this then you can write like :-

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static int ToInt(this Enum enum)
    {
        return (int)((object)enum);
    }
}
```

And use it as shown below :-

```
int x = WorkDays.MondayToFriday.ToInt();
```

Comment: yes i have tried this and it ok but i dont want to assign any of the enum values i want get the choosed value from my view

Comment: Or will it change to the value coming from the controller?

Comment: sorry I am not able to get what you want to say @user3811481

Comment: @user3811481 All of your code unless client side (e.g. javascript) is executed by your controllers in MVC on the server. That's the point, it's a server side technology. You'll need some kind of POST function to get whatever selection your user made back before you can cast it.

Comment: yes there is... Okay let me Edit the question and add my Post controller that insert using that service